# How to get around counterintuitive numpy behavior

Tags: python, numpy, types

consider the following:

```
foo = np.array(['a', 'b', 2])

bar = [x for x in foo if isinstance(x, str)]
```

Much to my surprise, what comes out is:

```
['a', 'b', '2']
```

So the 2 became a string. I understand that numpy is meant to deal with homogeneous arrays, but still, this is undesirable behavior, and would be nice to avoid. Suggestions?

Comment: What were you expecting or otherwise hoping to get?

Comment: @MarkMeyer that is (a) not very satisfying and (b) not clearly works, since pandas, like numpy, will cast everything in a column to "object"

Comment: @norok2 that was a joke, right? In case it was not, I was expecting `['a', 'b']`

Comment: I am not sure if you are unhappy with the content of `foo` or the content of `bar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy assumes `str` dtype in your case. Pass the `dtype` explicitly, e.g.:

```py
foo = np.array(['a', 'b', 2], dtype=object)
bar = [x for x in foo if isinstance(x, str)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure whats your problem here, but I guess you want that list to only have strings/chars of letters/words?

```py
import numpy as np
lst = ['a' ,'b', 2]
# ['a', 'b', 2]
foo = np.array([each for each in lst if str(each).isalpha()])
# array(['a', 'b'], dtype='<U1')
```

This ensures that only character will be in the bumpy array

Comment: My problem is, among other things, that I typed in `2` and got back `'2'`. You don't find that a problem?

Comment: You didint really specify whats your problem in the question